# how to make css background grid lines

Tags: css, background

[image: img]

---

There are four lines over the background. They are visible in overall sections but not over images.

How to make this?

Comment: Your chances of being answered depends on what you have been able to do to solve your problem. What have you done? Show some code.

Comment: I guess that is a background image you can set to your webpage.

Comment: No, it's not a background. My boss asked me to make this in CSS. I have no idea where to start.

Comment: You can also create [css background](http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/)

Comment: Just to clear some confusion... background img in CSS is not a <img> tag html. The effect is clearly done by using background-image in css.

Answer (score 11):

It is as easy as this

```css
body{
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #eee 1%, transparent 1%) 1px 0, #fff;
  background-size: 200px 1px;
}
```

DEMO: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VMzwNw

These and many other backgrounds can be generated using this site -> http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#stairs

Comment: Nicely answered, can you add the details how you created it.

Comment: this doesn't work on sections which have backround-image or background color. Works on sections which inherit body backround. How to make it visible over whole content?

Comment: It depends how you look at it. What if the page in shared picture: has such gradient set to body node and backgrounds for all other nodes are semi transparent? This way it could work, right?

Comment: This is great. I set `background-position: -1px` to remove the left line closest to browser edge and also set `background-size` to `calc((100% / 8) + 0.2px)` which removes the line on the right closest to browser edge. I also set gradient widths to `0.5%' instead of `1%` to make the lines thinner.

Comment: @MartinJames thanks for the extra answer. Would changing the background size to 12.5% achieve the same result as yours?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS linear gradients and multiple backgrounds to achieve this. Here's an example:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-size: 25% 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 1px, transparent 1px);
  background-position: 12.5%;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

The gradient draws a vertical line, whereas `background-size`, `background-position` and `background-repeat` combined make the vertical line repeat.

Here's an example with a background image and the vertical lines:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-size: 25% 100%, cover;
  background-repeat: repeat-x, no-repeat;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 1px, transparent 1px), url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
  background-position: 12.5%, center;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```